# COUNT with set DIFFERENCE and UNION

Tags: postgresql, except

Fairly simple question that I can't seem to find an answer to - I'm working with unions and differences, and I would like to perform a COUNT on the results. Currently I'm having to pipe out to a file and "wc -l" the file (minus 4 for the Postgres printing). There's got to be a way to include COUNT...

```
SELECT tbl1.id EXCEPT (SELECT tbl2.id UNION tbl3.id);
```

I would like to know the number of results after the set difference. Thanks for any input!

Comment: If you want only the count, why not do the following: `SELECT count(id) FROM (SELECT tbl1.id EXCEPT (SELECT tbl2.id UNION tbl3.id)) a;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT tbl1.id
    FROM tbl1 EXCEPT
    (
    SELECT tbl2.id
    FROM tbl2

    UNION

    SELECT tbl3.id
    FROM tbl3
    )
) AS t;
```

Comment: Doesn't look correct. Seems to get the `COUNT` then `EXCEPT` some ids from that number.

Comment: That'll teach me for not testing. Edited & that'll definitely work.

Comment: Nearly definitely. [Subqueries specifying a derived table must ... be assigned a table alias name](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-table-expressions.html) in postgres

Comment: I'll get my coat... :)

Comment: Yep - before your edit that is what I originally tried without success. This looks good - although I haven't "sanity checked" the result. Like Martin said, the only change is to alias the outside SELECT statement. Thanks!

Comment: This will also work: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT id FROM tbl1 EXCEPT SELECT id FROM tbl2 EXCEPT SELECT id FROM tbl3) AS t;`

Comment: @ypercube that's worthy of a separate answer I think :-)

Answer (score 5):

Another way to have the same result is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
  ( SELECT id FROM tbl1 
  EXCEPT 
    SELECT id FROM tbl2 
  EXCEPT 
    SELECT id FROM tbl3
  ) AS t ;
```

Comment: This works nicely.